# QQuickWidget send signal from c++ to slot in QML

Tags: c++, qt

I have a application and I want make a little animation for it.
I did a qml file and used QQuickWidget to open and show it in my display. Now a I want make iteration between c++ and QML. I want, for example, when a function in c++ is called, a ball move in my display. But I could not make a connection between c++ and qml.

Every help is welcome.

A little part of my code:
c++

```
QQuickWidget *quickWidget = new QQuickWidget;

quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/QML/main.qml"));
auto rootObject = quickWidget->rootObject();

// Connect C++ signal to QML slot
connect(this, SIGNAL(cppSignal()), rootObject, SLOT(qmlSlot()));

emit cppSignal();
```

QML

```
Rectangle {
id: tela
visible: true
width: 715
height: 77
color: '#E8E8E8'


//        NumberAnimation {
//            running: true
//            target: bolinha
//            property: "x"
//            duration: 1000
//            to: 600
//        }

function qmlSlot() {
    bolinha.visible= enabled
    animBolinha.start();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUCHR.png)

What I can do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can call a QML method from C++ code as you did.

**The recommended way from QT documentation is:**

All QML methods are exposed to the meta-object system. As the functions are exposed to meta-object system, you can use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`, to invoke the QML function.

Probably in your case, you should call as said below (not tested).

```
auto rootObject = quickWidget->rootObject();
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(rootObject, "qmlSlot");
```

Look [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#invoking-qml-methods) (search for ***Invoking QML Methods***)

As said in documentation, you can use `Q_ARG` to pass the arguments and `Q_RETURN_ARG` for receiving return arguments.